# Javascript xml parsing doctype entities

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I am using the standard DOMParser() (Browser built in XML parser) to create a XMLDocument-Object in JS. This works really great, however the doctype.entities NodeMap keeps being empty, even if it is set correctly in the XML Document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tag1 [
  <!ENTITY hello "hello1">
  <!ENTITY there "there1">
]>

<tag1>Stuff in here</tag1>
```

The JS-function looks like this:

```
function(xmlString)
{
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
  var docEntities = xmlDoc.doctype.entities;
  //Do stuff with the docEntities 
}
```

docEntities should by definition be a NodeMap with the Entities, but even though xmlDoc.doctype is an DocumentType-Object, it is not defined.
Why does the Parser not do that?